# Mongoose (mongodb) $push data as subdocument, validate unique?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a User document which has a Notes subdocument.
I'm using the following code to push new notes for the user with the given email address.

```
UserSchema.statics.addNotesToUser = function (email, notes, callback) {
    return this.updateOne(
        {'email': email},
        {$push: {notes}},
        callback
    )
};
```

This is working fine, however it's ignoring my unique constraint on the NoteSchema. these are my schemas

```
const NoteSchema = new Schema({
    _id: false,
    id: {type: String, required: true, trim: true, unique: true},
    content: {type: String, required: true, trim: true, lowercase: true},
    added: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    used: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    book: {
        name: {type: String, required: true}
    }
});

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true, trim: true, lowercase: true, unique: true},
    notes: [NoteSchema]
});
```

> I'm wondering how I can make sure that when pushing new notes to my user, I can validate if the ID of the notes is unique.

Thank you.

Comment: Any specific  reason you disable the _id in notes via `_id: false` and then try to create and validate new unique one? That is the whole idea of the `_id` mongo field.

Comment: I removed that part. Still not sure how I can add an array of objects with validation. Instead of just one

Comment: You most likely would need to provide a custom validate function for that field in mongoose and in that function just loop through and validate.

Comment: Is there another way of doing it? Like creating all models from a loop and inserting in one query. Or isn't there such a thing as insertMany for subdocuments?

Answer (score -1):

To achieve uniqueness constraint like functionality in subdocuments, hope that's OK.

```
  let notesId = [];
    notes.forEach(function(val,index){
       notesId.push(val.id)
    })
    db.yourCollection.update(
         { 'email': email, 'NoteSchema.id': { '$ne': { $each: notesId } }},
         {$push: {notes} },
        callback)
```

Comment: There's multiple notes. Where would I get that id variable then? Thanks.

Comment: You need to separate the id's from original.

Comment: Hmh it's adding null to my users notes array and it created a whole new table. You sure your code is correct? Thank you

Comment: Yupp, you can apply.

Comment: There's no ID with NoteSchema  `_id: false`  therefore this code will not work.